# Get total number of items in array

Tags: smarty

How can I get the total number of items in an array using Smarty? Can I use `{$smarty.foreach.foo.total}`?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

This question is answered on Smarty's FAQ page: http://smarty.incutio.com/?page=SmartyFrequentlyAskedQuestions#template-1

**Q:** *How do I count the number of elements in an array?*
**A:**  `{$array|@count}`

The `@` applies the modifier directly to the array instead of each individual element.